# Python – Pandas: Get max value of last 5 days

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file with two columns, date and price. I want to create a 3rd column with the max value of "Price" for the last 5 days. Not the last 5 rows or index, but 5 days.

Content of "example.csv"

```html
Date            Price
2018-07-23 124.44
2018-07-24 125.49
2018-07-25 123.26
2018-07-31 124.08
2018-08-01 125.10
2018-08-04 121.41
2018-08-05 119.17
2018-08-06 118.58
```

It should look like this:

```html
Date            Price   High5
2018-07-23 124.44  124.44
2018-07-24 125.49  125.49
2018-07-25 123.26  125.49
2018-07-31 124.08  124.08
2018-08-01 125.10  125.10
2018-08-04 121.41  125.10
2018-08-05 119.17  125.10
2018-08-06 118.58  121.41
```

With this code I get the max of the whole "Close" colum for every row.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
df['High5'] = df['Close'].max()

print(df)
```

With this code I get the max of the last 5 days ending with 2018-08-06 for all rows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
rng = pd.date_range(end='2018-08-06', periods=5, freq='D')
df['High5'] = df['Price'].loc[rng].max()

print(df['High5'])
```

I don't want the same value for all rows. And I know that it's wrong to work with a fix (ending) date. But I don't know the answer with my beginners knowledge.

Comment: What about weekends?  Do those count as days?

Comment: Also, the last expect High5 price appears wrong.  Rolling five would be Aug 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th, with the high price of 121.41 during this period.

Comment: You're right, I've now corrected the last high. Thanks for your respond.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for rolling

```
df=df.set_index('Date')
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.rolling('5 D').max()
#df=df.rolling('5 D').max().reset_index()
Out[62]: 
             Price
Date              
2018-07-23  124.44
2018-07-24  125.49
2018-07-25  125.49
2018-07-31  124.08
2018-08-01  125.10
2018-08-04  125.10
2018-08-05  125.10
2018-08-06  121.41
```

Comment: `df.assign(High5=df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.Date)).Price.rolling('5d').max().values)`

Comment: Great, MANY THANKS!